# "On a daily life" or "In a daily life"?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing an essay and when I wanted to use this phrase I realised that I am not certain which one to use. Which one is true?

*Whole sentence: "On a daily life, we humans see, hear, smell, taste and sense lots of things."*

Comment: I think you mean either “on a daily basis” or “in our daily lives”.

Comment: Yeap. The meaning I am trying to give is the second one. "In our daily lives". I should use this phrase.

Answer (score 4):

I think the phrase you may be looking for is 'In everyday life......'. That is the commonly-used one in this context.

Answer (score -4):

Correct sentence: "In a daily life, we humans see, hear, smell, taste and sense lots of things."

Comment: This is incorrect; the expression **in daily life** is idiomatic but doesn't have an article. Other similar constructions are possible, but **in *a* daily life** is not used.